# Install cartopy using pip on mac os and macports

Tags: python, macos, gis, cartopy

I am trying to install [`cartopy`](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/) on OS X 10.10 (Yosemite). My python is installed using macports and when I run:

```
sudo pip install cartopy
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/clang -Wno-unused-result -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -pipe -Os -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include -I./lib/cartopy -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/include/python3.4m -c lib/cartopy/trace.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.10-x86_64-3.4/lib/cartopy/trace.o

lib/cartopy/trace.cpp:236:10: fatal error: 'geos_c.h' file not found

#include "geos_c.h"

         ^

1 error generated.

error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-hwrcv0a1/cartopy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ytar95bq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hwrcv0a1/cartopy
```

Note that I installed the dependencies as noted [here](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html#installing) and `geos_c.h` can be found in `/opt/local/include`. It seems like `pip` fails to find this dependency in the `macports` tree.

Did anyone experienced this kind of problem? How can I fix it?

This question was also raised as an issue at https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/535.

Answer (score 0):

There was recently a bit of work to improve the `pip install cartopy` experience. Would you mind trying it again with cartopy v0.12.0.

See https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/610 for reference.

Comment: OK of the box it still doesn't work. The error I get is: `lib/cartopy/_crs.c:236:10: fatal error: 'proj_api.h' file not found
    #include "proj_api.h"
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1`

Answer (score 0):

This is to answer the last question from Dror, since I am using macports and "pip install cartopy" failed to find "proj_api.h". To solve this:

1. You need to make sure that the proj port is installed: `sudo port install proj`
2. Help pip to locate the header in "/opt/local/include": `CFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include" pip install cartopy`

Cheers and HTH

Comment: I had to use `PATH="$PATH:/opt/local/lib/proj49/bin" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib/proj49/lib" CFLAGS="-I/opt/local/lib/proj49/include" pip install --upgrade cartopy`. Proj4 is now in a different directory.